# .htaccess force http to https complex structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess

complex structure need to redirect variable files under variable folders to https

1st

```
example.com/business/variable-folders/variable-file
```

e.g.

```
example.com/business/business-manager/2344642
example.com/business/company-lawyer/146785
example.com/business/cleaning/5876441235
```

2nd

```
example.com/variable-folders/variable-file
```

e.g.

```
example.com/business-manager/local-state
example.com/motel/western-state
```

So far, I've been using the configuration below, but it does not account for the structure needed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$)
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/business^([^/]+)/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? ANd where did you encounter a problem? PLease provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your server configuration that underlines the problem you encountered during your attempts to solve this.

Comment: the  below code is not with the above structure     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$) 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/business/^([^/]+)/$1 [R,L]

Comment: I've added your last comment to the question.

Comment: please change the domain to example.com instead of actual domain name in the code. :)

Comment: Done, but you can do so yourself. Question has an "Edit" button below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following code to .htaccess file in

1-root folder

2-example/business/ folder

3- each folder for example.com/variable-folders/variable-file   for each subfolder

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+..+.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]